# 414 error in Google login in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, server, http-status-code-414

I have a worpdress site and when i try to login through google i get error 414 after filling in the login credentials. The site is running in my server, I'm using mysql to databse, php 8.1 and nginx as web server.
After some searching for help i saw that 414 error is causing because the URI is too long. One solution I saw was to add some settings to nginx.conf file, so I add this:

```
http {
...
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

        client_max_body_size 24M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        client_header_buffer_size 5120k;
        large_client_header_buffers 16 5120k;
...
}
```

I restarted nginx but I got the same error again :(
Some can help me pleaseeee!!!

Comment: How long is the URL?

Comment: The URL have 1522 chars